# Push data from dashDB to Watson Analytics using DataWorks?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, dashdb, dataconnect

I have an account in IBM Public Bluemix. I provisioned a dashDB instance and have inserted data into a dashDB table. I login to Bluemix using my IBM ID (not IBM Intranet ID)

I also have a Watson Analytics account. Please note that my Watson Analytics account/access is part of a larger team. I do not access it using the short Watson Analytics URL https://watson.analytics.ibmcloud.com. I access my account using https://watson.analytics.ibmcloud.com/home/data?loginAccountId=3ZPDZ2KL8DE0&loginTenantId=1VRPUK1QI0A5. when I go to this URL, it redirects me to IBM Intranet Authentication page and I login using IBM Intranet ID (not IBM ID).

I need to push data from the Bluemix dashDB table to the Watson Analytics account that I have.

when I create a connection in Bluemix DataWorks, it does not allow me to specify Watson Analytics URL. It allows me to enter only the user name and password. I created a connection for Watson Analytics using my IBM ID. And then created an activity to move data from dashDB to Watson Analytics. When I run the activity it fails. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow steps as in the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WAq3qVpENo
Instead of using bluemix dataWorks service, use the integrated dataworks within watson analytics by creating the data connections using dashDB credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an IBM internal userid that is not currently supported by DataWorks accessed via Bluemix.  Short term, you will have to use the integrated DataWorks support.  Unless you are developing a Bluemix application that needs to automatically push data, this will meet your needs.

Unless you are performing DataWorks cleansing operations on your data in dashDB, you can push your data into Watson Analytics directly via the API.